# How to insert image in the column (jsPDF autotable)?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a problem to show the image in the pdf file, pdf file not accept the image format.Is want to add plugin for images js code? I have tried to encode the picture then to generate the PDF file, but it doesn't work. Below is my code:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>

<button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>

<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td>Janice</td>
      <td>Henry</td>
      <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
      <td>Ukraine</td>
      <td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" /></td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  
  doc.autoTable({
    html: '#mytable',
    bodyStyles: {minCellHeight: 15},
    didDrawCell: function(data) {
      if (data.column.index === 5 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
         var td = data.cell.raw;
         var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
         var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
         var textPos = data.cell.textPos;
         doc.addImage(img.src, textPos.x,  textPos.y, dim, dim);
      }
    }
  });

    function generate() {  

      doc.save("table.pdf");
    }
</script>
```

Below is my output:

[image: output 1]

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: If the below solution is working please accept it as answer

Comment: textPos.x is undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move pdf configuration logic to **generate** function.

```
function generate() {
      var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.autoTable({
    html: '#mytable',
    bodyStyles: {minCellHeight: 15},
    didDrawCell: function(data) {
      if (data.column.index === 5 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
         var td = data.cell.raw;
         var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
         var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
         var textPos = data.cell.textPos;
         doc.addImage(img.src, textPos.x,  textPos.y, dim, dim);
      }
    }
  });

      doc.save("table.pdf");
    }
```

working example:- https://codepen.io/someatoms/pen/vLYXWB?editors=1010

Comment: If I move pdf configuration logic to generate function my side cannot work. Is I missed some include script?

Comment: i have an HTML content with both Table and other content. Your solution will help only if the HTML file has only Table. What if we want to diplay both HTML Table and other content?